# Grouping unique values in a vector and putting them in a matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing, unique

I have a vector that contains repeated numbers like so:

`[1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 93 93 93 6 6 6 6 6 6]` and so on. What I want to do is to group the similar values (1's, 5's, etc.). I would like to have each of the unique values in a row of a big matrix, like:

```
[ 1  1  1  1  0  0

  5  5  5  5  0  0

 93 93 93  0  0  0

  6  6  6  6  6  6]
```

I don't know the maximum number of occurrence of a unique value, so it is ok to create an initial zero matrix with a large number of columns (that I am sure is bigger than the maximum number of occurrence of a unique value).
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the repeated numbers always in a row, as in your example? Or could it be `[1 1 5 1 5 ...]`?

Comment: @LouisMendo Yes, they are always in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
A = [1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 93 93 93 6 6 6 6 6 6];
[a,b] = hist(A,unique(A))

f = @(x) [ones(1,a(x)) zeros(1,max(a)-a(x))]

X = cell2mat( arrayfun(@(x) {f(x)*b(x)}, 1:numel(b) )' )
```

returns:

```
X =

     1     1     1     1     0     0
     5     5     5     5     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     6
    93    93    93     0     0     0
```

I know the order is different, is that important? Otherwise:

```
n = hist(A,1:max(A))           % counts how often every number apperas
[a b] = unique(A,'stable')     % gets all unique numbers
n = n(a)                       % correlates count and numbers

f = @(x) [ones(1,n(x)) zeros(1,max(n)-n(x))]     % creates the logical index 
                                                 % vector for every single row

X = cell2mat( arrayfun(@(x) {f(x)*b(x)}, 1:numel(b) )' )  %fills the rows
```

---

or inspired by Luis Mendo's Answer **a little shorter**:

```
n = hist(A,1:max(A));
a = unique(A,'stable')
n = n(a)
Y = repmat(a',1,max(n)).*bsxfun(@le, cumsum(ones(max(n),numel(n))), n)'
```

returns:

```
X =

     1     1     1     1     0     0
     5     5     5     5     0     0
    93    93    93     0     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     6
```

---

For the bored people out there, there is a one-line solution:

> `X = getfield(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) padarray( padarray(x,[0 y],'replicate','pre'),[0 max(hist(A,1:max(A)))-y],'post'),1:max(A),hist(A,1:max(A)),'uni',0)'),{unique(A,'stable'),2:1+max(hist(A,1:max(A)))})`

Or an almost lovely two-liner:

```
n = hist(A,1:max(A))
X = getfield(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) padarray( padarray(x,[0 y],'replicate',...
    'pre'),[0 max(n)-y],'post'),1:max(A),n,'uni',0)'),...
    {unique(A,'stable'),2:1+max(n)})
```

just for fun ;)

Comment: can you please add some comment to your code, I can't fully understand the logic

Comment: @H_A - it is hard to comment everything - but if you have a look at all the intermediate results in your workspace it should be clear

Answer (score 5):

Vectorized solution (no loops):

```
x = [1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 93 93 93 6 6 6 6 6 6]; %// data
ind = [find(diff(x)) numel(x)]; %// end of each run of equal values
values = x(ind); %// unique values (maintaining order)
count = diff([0 ind]); %// count of each value
result = bsxfun(@le, meshgrid(1:max(count),1:numel(values)), count.'); %'// mask
result = bsxfun(@times, result, values.'); %'// fill with the values
```

*EDIT:*

Alternative procedure that avoids the second `bsxfun`:

```
x = [1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 93 93 93 6 6 6 6 6 6]; %// data
ind = [find(diff(x)) numel(x)];
values = x(ind); %// unique values (maintaining order)
count = diff([0 ind]); %// count of each value
mask = bsxfun(@le, ndgrid(1:max(count),1:numel(values)), count);
result = zeros(size(mask)); %// pre-allocate and pre-shape (transposed) result
result(mask) = x; %// fill in values
result = result.';
```

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! It feels a little cumbersome to have to use `bsxfun` twice, though

Comment: They must include one more functionality 'letimes' for bsxfun :)

Answer (score 2):

This could be one approach -

```
%%// Input
array1 = [1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 93 93 93 6 6 6 6 6 6];

%// Main Processing
id = unique(array1,'stable'); %//Find the unique numbers/IDs
mat1 = zeros(numel(id),nnz(array1==mode(array1))); %%// Create a matrix to hold the final result
for k=1:numel(id)
    extent_each_id = nnz(array1==id(k)); %%// Count of no. of occurances for each ID
    mat1(k,1:extent_each_id)=id(k); %%//  Starting from the left to the extent for each ID store that ID
end
```

Gives -

```
mat1 =
     1     1     1     1     0     0
     5     5     5     5     0     0
    93    93    93     0     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     6
```

Comment: You have to replace `median` with `mode`.

Comment: @Divakar your code worked perfectly fine, the advantage of other solutions is that for loop is avoided

Comment: @H_A bsxfun is vectorized, but arrayfun and repmat internally work on per-element basis and aren't vectorized approaches. Do runtime comparisions to make it a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Divakaryour On average, your code took 0.7 seconds to run versus 0.2 seconds for 'thewaywewalk' solution. The vector size is (73246*1).